# VB.Net SocketException was unhandled

Tags: vb.net, sockets, socketexception

In VB.Net I am trying to code a application that will check to see if an application is running or not using this code

```
Dim s As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
    Dim success
    Dim result
    result = s.BeginConnect("127.0.0.1", 8485, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf s.EndConnect), s)
    success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000, True)
    'Label12.Text = "Online"
    'Label12.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen



    If success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000, True) Then
        Label12.Text = "Online"
        Label12.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen
    End If




    Dim s2 As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
    Dim success2
    Dim result2
    result2 = s2.BeginConnect("127.0.0.1", 8484, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf s2.EndConnect), s2)
    success2 = result2.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000, True)
    'Label27.Text = "Online"
    'Label27.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen


    If success2 = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000, True) Then
        Label27.Text = "Online"
        Label27.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen
    End If


    Dim s3 As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
    Dim success3
    Dim result3
    result3 = s3.BeginConnect("127.0.0.1", 1111, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf s3.EndConnect), s3)
    success3 = result3.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000, True)
    'Label46.Text = "Online"
    'Label46.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen


    If success3 = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000, True) Then
        Label46.Text = "Online"
        Label46.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen
    End If
```

The application works perfectly if all of them are online, however if one of them are offline Visual Studio throws "SocketException was unhandled"

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: There is nothing to 'fix' - this is an exception. Have a look into exception handling in .net

Comment: @MattWilko Can you elaborate more?